# The Probability of ... After n Trials

Tags: math, statistics, probability

The probability of receiving a Penance Queen Pet from Barbarian Assault is 1/1000. I want to know the probability that you WON'T receive the pet after 1000 games, or trials.

`binompdf(1000, 1/1000, 0) equates to 36.8%`

Is this correct? It's a much higher probability than I was expecting.

Comment: Note that (1-1/N)^N converges (slowly) towards `exp(-1)=0.367879441..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the probability of not recieving the pet in one game. Which is 1-1/1000 right?

Now you must assume that you failed 1000 games in a row.

Failed Once `and` Failed Once `and` Failed Once .... `and` Failed Once
that is equal to (1-1/1000)*(1-1/1000)...*(1-1/1000)
Which is `1-1/1000 raised to 1000`
As you can see, the probability is 36,7695%

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why that didn't occur to me.